# Локальная переменная цикла

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def foo():
   for i in [1,2,3,4,5]:
       x = i
   print(x,i)
```

Почему вызов функции не выдаёт ошибок, ведь x и i определены внутри цикла, а доступ к ним осуществляется вне его?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, блок `for` не создаёт новой области видимости. Как переменная цикла, так и переменные объявленные в блоке, станут переменными объемлющей области.

Comment: То есть нельзя использовать одинаковые переменные в двух соседних циклах?

Comment: @user329125, что вам запрещает это сделать? Ничего не мешает использовать одно и то же имя переменной несколько раз. Просто старое значение при очередном присваивании будет теряться.